# vim: indenting bullet/lists within comments (in python)

Tags: vim, auto-indent

vim indents lists (or bullets) within text files fine:

```
- this is item one that 
  is indented correctly
- this is item two that 
  is also indented 
  correctly
```

I can type `gqap` within the paragraph above, and the formatting and indenting work correctly.

However, this doesn't work within python comments, and gets indented like so:

```
# - this is item one that 
# is not indented correctly
# - this is item two that 
# is also not indented 
# correctly
```

If I type `gqap` within the python comment above, vim doesn't even recognize the bullet points. and ends up formatting the entire block into a paragaph.

So with respect to bullets and indenting, how do I get vim to behave the same way inside python comments as it does within a regular text file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a pretty hard problem that is not obviously documented even though it is very well supported by formatlistpat. I was able to support multiple styles of lists just by identifying formatlistpat and formatoptions as the settings I wanted to play with in my vimrc.

You can get a full overview with the following:

```
:help 'formatlistpat'
:help 'formatoptions'
```

Your working example indicates that you like the way that vim transforms the
following:

```
- this is item one that 
is indented correctly
- this is item two that 
is also indented 
correctly
```

By entering gqap or gqip in normal mode you get the following:

```
- this is item one that is indented correctly
- this is item two that is also indented correctly
```

But there is a problem in that you cannot indent unorder lists in vim with your configuration if you are presented with something like the following:

```
# - this is item one that 
# is not indented correctly
# - this is item two that 
# is also not indented 
# correctly
# + this is item one that 
# is not indented correctly
# + this is item two that 
# is also not indented 
# correctly
# * this is item one that 
# is not indented correctly
# * this is item two that 
# is also not indented 
# correctly
```

In this case gpaq will incorrectly format to the following:

```
# - this is item one that is not indented correctly - this is item two that
# is also not indented correctly + this is item one that is not 
# indented correctly + this is item two that is also not indented  
# correctly * this is item one that is not indented correctly * this 
# is item two that is also not indented  correctly
```

**You can immediately  correct this indentation issue with the following:**

```
:set formatoptions+=n
:set formatlistpat=^\\s*[\\-\\+\\*]\\+\\s\\+
```

Which will reformat your comment in the way that you intend:

```
# - this is item one that is not indented correctly
# - this is item two that is also not indented correctly
# + this is item one that is not indented correctly
# + this is item two that is also not indented correctly
# * this is item one that is not indented correctly
# * this is item two that is also not indented correctly
```

There are other lists you nay want to support too:

```
# a) this is item one that is not
# indented correctly
# b) this is item two that is also not
# indented correctly
# C. this is item three that is also not
# indented correctly
```

Can be correctly formatted with:

```
:set formatlistpat=^\\s*\\w[.\)]\\s\\+
```

The following:

```
# 1 this is item one that 
# is not indented correctly
# 2) this is item two that 
# is also not indented 
# correctly
# 33. this is item three that 
# is also not indented 
# correctly
```

Can be correctly formatted with:

```
:set formatlistpat=^\\s*\\d\\+[.\)]\\s\\+
```

The following:

```
# i. this is item one that 
# is not indented correctly
# ii. this is item two that 
# is also not indented 
# correctly
# iv) this is item three that 
# is also not indented 
# correctly
```

Can be correctly formatted with:

```
:set formatlistpat=^\\s*[ivxIVX]\\+[.\)]\\s\\+
```

You can put that all together with two simple lines:

```
:set formatoptions+=n
:set formatlistpat=^\\s*\\w\\+[.\)]\\s\\+\\\\|^\\s*[\\-\\+\\*]\\+\\s\\+
```